# Test for n digits in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

I am trying to solve 'JavaScript Algorithms and Data Structures Projects: Telephone Number Validator' @freeCodeCamp.

I need to test if string contains 10 digits and what I've come up with returns false and I don't understand why.

```
console.log(/\d{10}/g.test("555-555-5555"))
```

Comment: The string doesn't just contain 10 digits - it also contains dashes.

Comment: Try this `console.log(/\d{10}/g.test("555-555-5555".replace(/\D/g, '')))`. This will remove the dashes before testing for length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with a single regular expression, you can use:

```js
console.log(/^(?:\D*\d){10}\D*$/g.test("555-555-5555"))
console.log(/^(?:\D*\d){10}\D*$/g.test("555-555-55555"))
```

requiring the input to be composed of exactly 10 digits in addition to any number of other non-digit characters - but replacing non-digits with the empty string first would be a more intuitive and readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here `\d{10}` means *ten consecutive digits*, not "ten digits with whatever in the middle, that's cool".

If want just 10 digits, you may want to strip non-digit data first:

```
let number = "555-555-5555";

// Remove all non-digit values (\D) which leaves only digits
let digits = number.replace(/\D/g, '').length;
```

Comment: So there is no way to use test method without deleting chars/creating new variable?

Comment: If you want to write a regular expression for that it comes out really ugly since it'll be like `\d\-?\d\-?\d\-?\d\-?\d\-?\d\-?\d\-?\d\-?\d\-?\d`, but that allows only one dash in the middle, so `555--555---5555` won't count.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your idea is correct, but this specific challenge has so many options for dashes [-] and parentheses [()] as inputs that there is a more efficient way to pass this.

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  let phoneRegex = /^(1\s?)?(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))[\s\-]?\d{3}[\s\-]?\d{4}$/
  return phoneRegex.test(str);
}
```

The above is a way to complete the challenge in a single line of Regex, which can save you (or anyone else reading this in the future) a lot of time and space! Cheers